# Expanding the path stored in a variable

Tags: linux, bash

Suppose I have a variable in my bash script:

```
conf="~/Downloads"
```

where `Downloads` is an existing directory under my home directory.

The following complains that directory does not exist:

```
realpath $conf
```

How do I expand a path stored in a variable?

Please note that, in the actual script of mine, `conf` contains input from user, who may or may not input tilde. Hence, writing `conf=~"/Downloads"` is not an option.

**UPDATE:** Unfortunately, the question has been marked as duplicate and I cannot reply. The solution is to transform the value by `eval "conf=$conf"`.

Comment: `conf=~/"Downloads"` or `conf="$HOME/Downloads"`

Comment: @Inian `conf` contains input from user, who may or may not input tilde. I edited the question to explain why it's not a duplicate.

Comment: try realpath "${conf/#~/$HOME}"